# Makefile share a target by overriding build variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, a part of which which looks like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: master dispatcher

.PHONY: master
master: BUILDTARGET=master
master: buildbin    ## Builds master

.PHONY: dispatcher
dispatcher: BUILDTARGET=dispatcher
dispatcher: buildbin    ## Builds dispatcher

.PHONY: buildbin 
buildbin:
@cd ${BUILD_FOLDER}/${BUILDTARGET} && ${MAKE} build GOBIN=${GOBIN} 
     LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}" CMD_FOLDER=${CMD_FOLDER}
@cd ${PROJECT_ROOT}
```

Please assume BUILD_FOLDER, GOBIN, LDFLAGS, CMD_FOLDER, PROJECT_ROOT to be set.

The trouble is running make always builds 'master' only and exits.
Changing the order of 'all', I found it was building the 1st one only.
What is wrong with the above Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use dependencies like this, `buildbin` is just another target and will be remade at most once per invocation. You can fix this as follows:

```
.PHONY: all master dispatcher
all: master dispatcher

master: BUILDTARGET=master
dispatcher: BUILDTARGET=dispatcher

master dispatcher:
    @cd ${BUILD_FOLDER}/${BUILDTARGET} && ${MAKE} build GOBIN=${GOBIN} LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}" CMD_FOLDER=${CMD_FOLDER}
    @cd ${PROJECT_ROOT}
```

Or more simply

```
.PHONY: all master dispatcher
all: master dispatcher

master dispatcher:
    @cd ${BUILD_FOLDER}/$@ && ${MAKE} build GOBIN=${GOBIN} LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}" CMD_FOLDER=${CMD_FOLDER}
    @cd ${PROJECT_ROOT}
```